# Dilemmas with Newton Laws of Dynamics, Frame of References, and friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

There's this problem I'm trying to solve, it's about Newton Laws of Dynamics. It goes like this:
an elevator is moving up at a constant acceleration of $ 1.9 m/s^2 $, on its floor there's a box with books whose mass is $ 36 kg $. A man is pushing the box towards elevator's door with a horizontal force, so the box is sliding on the floor at a constant velocity. The friction coefficient during the sliding of the box is 0.32. Find the magnitude of the horizontal force.

I have a few dilemmas about this problem:

1. Is a frame of reference that moves with a constant acceleration, like the elevator in this case  an inertial frame of reference and why? And if it's inertial what would the main difference be if it was a non-inertial and vice versa?
2. What is the main difference between a friction coefficient during sliding and a friction coefficient when a body is standing still?
3. I've assumed that the frame of reference is an inertial one and I've calculated $ 135 N $ as the magnitude of the horizontal force. Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Marko Gulin has given the correct answers to your questions 1 and 3 and there is no point for me to add anything about them.

However, he has not answered your question 2.

Friction when a body is standing still is larger than friction when it is sliding. Once the motion has started and the body slides you will find that the force to keep it sliding is less than the one needed to make it move in the first place. And this is **not** due to the acceleration you have to impart to it to increase its speed from zero to the sliding speed, which is usually much, much smaller than the difference between the "static friction", at rest, and "kinetic friction", in motion (divided by the mass, of course). The latter, however, is independent on the speed of the motion, contrary to fluid friction.

See [the wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction)